# AngularJS Rest call to authenticate user

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am trying to write a service to authenticate users on login:

```
//Authentication Service
app.factory("AuthenticationService", function($location, $http) {
  return {     
    login: function(credentials) {

    $http('api/auth/:username/:password',{'username': credentials.username, 'password' : credentials.password})
        .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
            if(data.success=="1"){
                //succefull login
                credentials.isLogged = true;
                credentials.username = data.username;
                return true;
            }
            else{
                credentials.isLogged = false;
                credentials.username = '';
                credentials.errormessage = "Login Failed! Try again...";
                return false;
            }
        })
        .error(function(data,status,headers,config){
            credentials.isLogged = false;
            credentials.username = '';        
            credentials.errormessage = "Login Error. Missing Service";
            return false;
        });

    },

    logout: function() {
      $location.path('/logout');
    },

    checkAuth: function(){
        if (credentials.isLogged) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $location.path('/admin/login');
        }
    }

  };
});
```

In the backend I have a PHP api that responds with:

```
[{'success':'0'}]
```

However I cannot manage to make the call appropriately from Angular, since it always return the "Login Error" message.

Can someone have a look at this code and tell me what I am doing wrong? (I guess many things). Thanks a lot

**EDIT**

I changed the PHP to return: 
**{'success':'0'}** (or 1, accordingly)
Also I tried

```
$http.post(...)
```

But I get 404. The URL is definitively correct, I must be doing something else wrongly...

Answer (score 1):

Try with {'success':'0'}, 
I mean you can't return arrays as root object.

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the index of the array where your object is contained:

```
if (data[0].success=="1")
```